# Xamarin Forms Dynamic Report

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dynamic, report

I need to make a report and I will show it on a Datagridview but information in this report has to be dynamic.

For Example:

Data come from api and it has 2 parameters Database Code and Database name but next time this  information has 2 parameters again and this time Product ID and Product Name. And this data doesn't have to be like that, It could has 10 parameters.

How can I this huge elastic dynamic report ? Can you give me an idea, example or something?

Comment: Did you try to create a model class which contains all the types of parameter and set it as the api's parameter? Or just pass a collection such as key-value as parameter?

Comment: " had thought about this, but I wasn't sure. If I organize the data from the API into column names and keys, would that work, right? @Liyun

Comment: Yes, you can have a try.